# run 'yarn install' stoped at 'MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit completed...'

Tags: webpack, jhipster, yarnpkg

my project is created by jhipster

when I run 'yarn install' , It work normally just few time.

then command line stop at this positon forever!

```
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":[./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/index.html] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/index.html 1.61 kB {0} [built]
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit starts...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit completed...
```

There isn't any  [error]  infomation.

can anybody tell how to check  or how to fix it.

thanks

OS: win7

yarn: 1.3.2

jhipster: 4.5.5

Comment: Any reason why you could not upgrade your project?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 is no longer supported by JHipster, notifications don't always work. When your build is blocked, please check the notification area of the taskbar (bottom right corner of screen) there could be some pending notification from JHipster build,clicking on it will unblock your build.